# Apps Script returns "Invalid HTML content"

Tags: google-apps-script

i created this feedback page: http://scratchpad.io/incredible-shape-3390
and use it as feedbck of this form (at the bootom right): https://eco4it.de/

if i send the form i get the error **Invalid HTML content**:

[image: Invalid HTML content:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the markup is invalid that's why it complains; just see for yourself: [htmlhint.io](https://htmlhint.io) (with `doctype-html5` and all standard hints enabled, there are about 50 things to improve). there are lots of typos; eg. `""`, many self-closing tags not properly closed. maybe get an IDE alike [NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html) or [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download), which makes editing HTML easier.

Comment: yes error changed as i changed line 226/227 in PHPstorm. compared (wrong, corrected): https://imgur.com/a/65JWlAv Wrong code: `style="padding:8;  font:font-family: Roboto; "><span style="style="font-family: 'Quicksand'""` ... that was a copy from another page the result looked good and I had not studied the source code before that (was no errors inside of : http://scratchpad.io/incredible-shape-3390 )